How to use a generic type in a type signature of another function?
I have these three helpers defined:
export type IdType = PropertyKey;
export type Identifiable<T> = T & {id: IdType};
export type IdGetter<T> = (x: Identifiable<T>) => IdType;

I would like to be able to type generic methods using the IdGetter generic, like (this doesn't work, but that's the sort of thing I would like to be able to do):
export const getId<T>: IdGetter<T> = x => x.id

But instead I have to write:
export const getId = <T>(x: Identifiable<T>): IdType => x.id;

It's not a big deal, I can still do things like that and have no type errors:
const f = <U, F extends IdGetter<U>>(getter: F) => (x: Identifiable<U>): IdType => getter(x);
f(getId);

But defining the types of these getters is redundant.
Is there a clean way to do what I'm looking for? I'm trying to get better at using generics.

TS is unfortunately not expressive enough to represent the relationship between those two function types in the type level. You have to do what you're doing, even if it's redundant. See the linked questions and answers above for more information.
